# Laravel Session Flash Message not showing on live server but shows on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I flash one particular message it shows on localhost but not on production server. What can be cause of this problem.All other messages are shown but not this one

```
//Blade Template
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(session('alert-' . $msg))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">
            {{ session('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

```
//Controller Code
return redirect('url')->with('alert-danger','All lines are already reserved, Please try again later.');

``

Also it does show up when I dd() the redirect object, see attached image


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ZXZ.png
```

Comment: Which session driver are you using on production and how is your application being hosted? Are you using containers?

Comment: I'm using google cloud.Only this one particular message is not flashed.All other work

Comment: so you are saying if you change the `with` to `with('alter-warning', ...)` it works fine?

Comment: No nothing works when I flash and redirect in this "If statement"

Comment: so what is it that you can flash that does show up?

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing manually, because redirect return a 301 HTTP response, not a view

```php
/*request()->*/session()->flash('alert-danger', 'All lines are already reserved, Please try again later.');
return redirect('url');
```

Comment: RedirectResponse has a `with` method, for flashing data to the session

Comment: yes but what you was trying to do is, to the view that return the method that is responsible for the ''url'', add this element, that is the same of flashing this element to the session, after the next request, this value expire... please try and than tell me what happens